# Origin and status of "hosed", meaning "broken"

Tags: etymology, slang

Are the etymology and status of *hosed* known, and if so, what are they?  For this question, "hosed" is used as at [onlineslangdictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-of/hosed) or at [urbandictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?defid=1123604&term=hosed). (That is, with meaning *broken, messed up, worn out*, rather than its probably-older "put hose on" or "attached hose" past-participle meanings.)

My question about the status of the word is whether it indubitably is slang, vs. being a "proper dictionary word".
I've always supposed it should be the latter, and imagined that dictionary compilers have left it out by mistake.

Note 1: as a plus, the onlineslangdictionary site tabulates votes on frequency of use and sense of vulgarity of words, and tabulates hundreds of recent tweets containing 'hosed'; perhaps as a minus, it gives a needlessly wordy definition: "utterly and undoubtedly affixiated in a troublesome situation".

Note 2: [ngrams.googlelabs.com](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=hosed%2Chosing&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) shows frequency of use of 'hosed' tripling between 1930 and 1940.

Update 1: Among answers given so far, the "police brutality [by] use of water via fire hoses" and/or "being beaten with a rubber hose" explanations seem less compelling than (i) the explanation stemming from *hose* as "transparent metaphor for the penis" (supported by specialised slang dictionary references) or (ii) the explanation based on [SCTV / Mackenzie Brothers / Great White North](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_and_Doug_McKenzie) reference and [Wikipedia *hoser*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoser) entry.  If it becomes more clear in a few days I'll checkmark an answer. - jiw

Comment: I would bet the increase has something to do with the increased availablity of rubber hoses.  The alternate became more common after "Strange Brew".

Comment: I can't find any references to "was hosed" with the "broken" meaning before 1988. And then it doesn't mean "broken," it applies to people, and it means "they were screwed." I'm guessing police tactics are the origin (although I would think if it were, the meaning would have dated to the late 1960s or the 1970s).

Comment: I believe this meaning is slang and probably dates from the early 90s or slightly before.  Earliest "is hosed" I found with the meaning was from 1992, most 1994 or later.  One instance, possibly related, was a rock climber being "_hosed_" (italics and quotes in original) in 1991, meaning wholly sore after a day of climbing.

Comment: In Google books, I find [two uses](http://www.google.com/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=%22we+were+hosed%22&tbs=,cdr:1,cd_min:Jan%201_2%201987,cd_max:Dec%2031_2%201988&num=10) of "we were hosed" with this meaning in 1987 and 1988.

Comment: Chad and Peter have it. Its a Bob and Doug Mackenzie reference. The skit first appeared in 1980, the album (that's how things went viral back in the 80's) two years later, the movie a year or so after that. That's why all Peter's references start in the 80s.

Comment: Could it be tied to Hosea from the Bible?

Comment: To confuse matters: It appears that commonwealth speakers still use the phrase "home and hosed" to mean home-free, or roughly the opposite!

Comment: I do not understand the question. The usages are just all mixed up and the question is generic. And this gets 15 upvotes?? How about an example of hosed "meaning broken"? Agree with Peter Shor, in slang, it means getting screwed.

Comment: Just an idea, but the first attestation I can find for "[beer bong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer_bong)" is [1978](https://books.google.com/books?id=qzd2CAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA203&dq=%22beer%20bong%22&pg=PA203#v=onepage&q=%22beer%20bong%22&f=false). That's one heck of a coincidence. This would then be a repurposing of the gas tank siphoner. Oh, so then I search for collocations and find [this](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hoser&page=8)

Comment: @PhilSweet, yes, it looks like a 1978 beer bong ref might be of interest; however, while your google books link says "Lulu.com, 1978 - 88 pages" re David von Beck's book *Coal*, other links, eg [Amazon.com](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B004MMEGC0/ref=dp-kindle-redirect?_encoding=UTF8&btkr=1), show a 2011 date.  Re the amusing ['this'](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=hoser&page=8) link, Urban Dictionary frequently is not the top item on lists of etymological resources.

Comment: My guess about ho from whore i'll apply to ho in hose (greg 12/9 romn 1:32pm). Both have sexual connotations so allude to Hosea and the Bible book Hosea

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Early on that word of course was used to talk about the action of cleaning something off with a garden hose, but that is **not** the meaning you are asking about. I do not recall ever hearing that term used with that meaning before the 80's. What happened in the 80's?

Well, [SCTV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_City_Television) had a very funny (to us USAsians) skit with a couple of stereotypical Canadians called the [McKenzie Brothers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_and_Doug_McKenzie). They were constantly calling each other "hosers", and talking about how they had "hosed" each other. The skit went the 80's equivalent of viral, with an album (with a couple of singles that got good airplay) and [a movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_Brew) spun off it. The effect was that we (in the USA) got "hoser" added to the language as sort of a good-natured insult, or a way to make fun of Canadian speech.

[image]

Along with it, we borrowed the verb and adverb forms of "hosed" from the same source. Its a much more useful word, so it kinda lost its association with Canadians, and got fully adopted into the USA lexicon.

So where did Canadians come up with these words? That's where personal experience fails me, so I have to rely on [online sources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoser):

> Like the very similar term hosehead, the term may have referred to
>   farmers of the Canadian prairies, who would siphon gas from farming
>   vehicles with a hose during the Great Depression of the
>   1930s.[citation needed] The expression has since been converted to the
>   verb 'to hose' as in to trick, deceive, or steal - for example: "That
>   card-shark sure hosed me." Hosed has an additional meaning of becoming
>   drunk - for example: "Let's go out and get hosed." Another possible
>   origin is derived from hockey slang. Before ice resurfacers, the
>   losing team in a hockey game would have to hose down the rink after a
>   game. Thus the term "hoser" being synonymous with "loser".

Personally I prefer the hockey explanation, but that doesn't make it right.

Currently the OED says there is [no clear evidence](http://mentalfloss.com/article/51399/where-does-word-hoser-come) of the term being used prior to its use by Rick Moranis and Dave Thomas, which to my mind leaves a strong possibility that they may have invented the slang themselves (although they *are* both Canadian, so they could well just be the first to record an existing slang).

Comment: Good lord but I remember that. I think it likely that the original derived from "hoosiers" a nickname for people from Indiana but was originally of Scandinavia origin and meaning spread westward up the Scandinavia settlement belt into Canada. Flatten out the vowel with a dose of Scottish brogue (and ethnic antipathy) and "hoosier" becomes "hosers". Just a guess.

Comment: Though I have no proof, both the hockey and siphoning explanations seem to me rather unlikely, right up there with "posh" coming from "port outward, starboard homeward" or "Jolly Roger" from "Jolie Rouge". These kinds of plausible explanation rarely seems to be the reality.

Comment: @fool4jesus - Very much agree. I'd vastly prefer something better than unsourced theories like this. One thing I noticed I didn't mention is that "hose-head" was used synonymously with "hoser" in the original B&D act. Perhaps that's a clue, but I think someone would have to do some serious research to track it down better. In the meantime though, I think the best "patient zero" we have for this as a term is B&D.

Comment: @fool4jesus - Did a bit more research, which seems just as skeptical as the two of us are, so I've added a bit of that to the answer.

Comment: @T.E.D. Interesting. I just did an ngram search and "hoser" has at times been used quite a bit (e.g. from 1939-1944) though until the 90's I didn't see any use with this meaning. That cited usage of "hosed" as "drunk" (which I've never heard personally) would seem to be related. Both "hosed" as "shafted" and "drunk" still seem to me most logically connected to the sexual derivation, since you can apply "f***ed" (possibly with "up") to either meaning.

Answer (score 12):

The etymology of *hosed* as *broken* is very similar to that of *screwed* or *fucked*.

In short, the metaphor is, unsurprisingly, that of a sexual act.  The *hose* is a transparent metaphor for the *penis*.

So that in the case of *hosed* as in that of *screwed* the semantic path is that of:

1. Analogy with sexual context.
2. => Meaning of *copulate*.
3. => Meaning of *cheat* or *deceive*.
4. => Meaning of *broken*.

Several specialised slang dictionaries back this interpretation:

The [McGraw Hill Ntc's Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions And Colloquial Expression (3rd Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071461078) for instance has the following entries.

**1. About the *penis* usage**

> **hose** 
> **1. n. the penis**. (Usually objectionable.)
>    *He held his hands over his* hose *and ran for the bedroom*. 
> **2.** tv. & in. **to copulate [with] a woman**. (Usually objectionable.) 
>    *You don’t like her, you just want to* hose *her!* 
> **3**. tv. to **cheat** or **deceive** someone; to **lie** to someone.
>    *Don’t try to* hose *me! I’m onto you! He’s just* hosing *you! Ignore him.*

**2. hoser (entry #3 is similar to *wanker*)**

> **hoser**
> **1**. n. a good guy or buddy. 
>    *Old Fred is a good* hoser*. He’ll help.* 
> **2**. n. a **cheater** or **deceiver**.  
>    *You dirty lying* hoser*!* 
> **3**. n. a **moron**; a **stupid acting person**. (Rude and derogatory.)
>    *Come here, you* hoser*. I’ll show you how to do it.*
>    *Bob is such a* hoser*! He never gets anything right*.

**3. to hose down as to kill**

> **hose someone down** tv. to **kill** someone. (Underworld. From the image of spraying someone with bullets.)
>    *Mr. Big told Bruno to* hose *Max down.*
>    *The thugs tried to* hose *down the witness.*

---

And the [Oxford Dictionary of Contemporary Slang](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0713675047) has complementary albeit similar entries:

> **hose** vb American to have sex with. A mainly male vulgarism.
>    *There must be someone here that I
> could hose...Better get some more
> sherry to smooth out my brain.*
>
> (S. Clay Wilson cartoon, Head Comix, 1968)
>
>
> **hose monster** n American
> an extremely promiscuous and/or sexually active person. The term, which may
> be used pejoratively or appreciatively, is particularly applied to heterosexual
> females. Compare shag-monster
>
> **hoser** n American
> **1**. a fraud, deceitful person, cheat  
> **2.** a promiscuous person, usually female
> Both senses of the term are found in the
> vocabulary of high-school and college students. The etymology of the word is not
> certain, but probably derives from hose as
> a noun meaning penis and a verb meaning
> to copulate or screw in the figurative sense
> of defraud.

Comment: Odd. The OED actually has this one wrong. "Hoser" as a noun only became popular in the USA after being used repeatedly by SCTV's Mackenzie brothers back in the 80's as a funny stereotypical thing said by Canadians. I believe it is still only used here when making fun of Canadian speech.

Comment: @T.E.D. Look at the bottom of the *hose* entry in the OED.  Mine says "Draft partial entry December 2004 ▸ N. Amer. slang. The penis. 1928 in A. W. Read Lexical Evid. Folk Epigraphy Western N. Amer. (1935) 59 So now kind friends remember before the water flows please ajust [sic] the distance according to your hose.    1947W. Guthrie in R. Shelton Born to Win (1965) 60 This hose, this dong, dick, this stick and rod and staff of birth.    1978 L. Kramer Faggots 252 Think every name from every stage of your educational development!‥gadget, hammer, hang-down, honker, hose [etc.].

Comment: ...so, at least when Americans use it, it generally has nothing to do with sex.

Comment: Alain, Note how old all those references are (except for the '70s ones, which IMHO are self-explained, not a common usage of the word). I'm sorry, but they have this one wrong. It happens on occasion. Still, I'm as surprised by it as you.

Comment: @T.E.D. The reason why these are old citations is simply that the whole list wouldn't fit in an EL&U comment.  The last one is dated 1999.

Answer (score 3):

There was a recurring *Saturday Night Live* sketch in the late 70s with Dan Aykroyd and Steve Martin as the "Wild and Crazy" Czechoslovakian brothers. [In one](http://snltranscripts.jt.org/77/77rfestrunks.phtml) of those sketches, Garrett Morris told them "You've been hosed." To which Martin replies "Hosed? Count me in!" a reference to the sexual meaning. But Morris explained "No, hosed! tricked! I mean they stood you up, man!" I think this slightly predated the "Great White North" routine.

In the 1950s, American Fighter pilots used the term to mean shooting at. As in, "Hose him!" See *Boyd: The Fighter Pilot Who Changed the Art of War*. A fascinating book, by the way. In the 1960s he was promoted to the Pentagon, and was known for often using the term to mean to get the upper hand over a rival. Close to the modern meaning.

Comment: These are some interesting details, but they don't really answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

If your earliest memories of police brutality are the use of water via fire hoses on civil rights demonstrators, you would likely guess that as the origin.

But I'm guessing that being beaten with a rubber hose (supposedly to not leave bruises, like with a baton), again by police, is more likely the origin, and would explain the term predating the civil rights marches.

Comment: But the term doesn't predate the civil rights marches ... the first use anybody has found is 1988.

Comment: Then what is "ngrams.googlelabs.com shows frequency of use of 'hosed' tripling between 1930 and 1940" using as data?

Comment: That would be the word *hosed* meaning washing something down with a hose. That's not the meaning the OP is asking about.

Comment: Not a bad guess, but this isn't it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be ignoring the fact that the penis reference from the 20's, and the general referring to the penis as a hose led to it becoming a euphemism for "f**king".
If you used that hose to have sex with it, then you would be hosing someone.  Extend all the meanings of "f**king" "getting f**ked" "getting screwed" etc. and hosing, getting hosed, hoser
and so on. Tie all of the references together and there you go, eh?

Answer (score 1):

In my shop the system was first "hosed" and then some bright guy made the "host operating system error detected" comment.  Hosed was in use around Chicago about/prior(?) to the SCTV skits in the mid-70s.

Comment: Apparently the Bob and Doug McKenzie segments [first appeared in 1980](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_City_Television#Bob_.26_Doug_McKenzie), so it would be good to see some references supporting your assertion that it was an *American* usage several years before what most people seem to think was a *Canadian* usage took off.

Answer (score 1):

The 1924 Mack Sennett comedy "Lizzies of the Field" shows a sign in an auto garage offering steam cleaning, except "Fords are hosed"
http://moviessilently.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/lizzies-of-the-field-1924-mack-sennett-billy-bevan-silent-movie-image-06.jpg

Comment: Could you explain further why you think the sign means "Fords are broken" rather than "Fords are cleaned with a hose"?

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought *hosed* was simply the past of passive participle of *hose*.  Apart from the old meaning of being clothed, I would have thought it would also mean being sprayed by water from a hosepipe, and this is what led to the broken meaning.

Incidentally [Google ngrams](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=hosed,hosing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) has *hosing* rising in popularity with *hosed* in the 1940s.

Comment: Some of those usages in the 40's could have had to do with nylon pantyhose, and thus have nothing to do with the meaning in the OQ.

Comment: ...or as Peter Shor mentions in another comment, the act of having "hosed something down", which is (probably) a different meaning entirely.

Answer (score -2):

HOSED means Host Operating System Error Detected.

Before Windows this was the same as the blue screen of death.

If your system was HOSED, it was halted with no recovery.

Comment: Some references would be good...

Comment: I've been programming since the mid 70's, and this term rings no bell whatsoever to me. [Google can't find](https://www.google.com/search?q=host+operating+system+detected&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb#rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&q=host+operating+system+error+detected) it either. "Before Windows" makes no sense, as there were oodles of different platforms and OS'es. You could mean MS-DOS, but I'm pretty sure DOS had no such error.